# Obtener conexión a base de datos a través del datasource del servidor de aplicaciones

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, jboss-eap, oracle-12c

se me presenta la siguiente situación: tengo un proyecto web que voy a desplegar en un servidor jboss eap 7.1, en el servidor he creado un datasource de conexión a la base de datos, la cual funciona correctamente; las tablas y vistas que debo de modificar no fueron creadas con llaves primarias por lo cual hacer una mapping con JPA no es posible, por lo cual he pensado realizar sentencias de sql nativas  desde un datasource, sin embargo en lo que he investigado, en internet, los ejemplos siempren colocan los datos de conexión en el código java, mi cuestión es ¿ como puedo obtener una conexión a la base de datos desde el datasource configurado en el servidor? la base de datos es una oracle 12c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Para acceder a recursos definidos en un servidor JEE, usa JNDI.

Aunque los conceptos no son complicados, los detalles técnicos tienen sus detallitos y hace tiempo que no tengo que ponerme a definir estas cosas. En todo caso creo que (visto que no hay otras respuestas) mejor darte una respuesta aproximada que pueda fallar en algún detalle que no que no haya respuesta.

Como comentaba, tu Datasource estará definido en el JNDI. Normalmente estará dentro del *namespace* `java:` (p.ej. `java:miDataSource`) o `java:jboss/`<sup>1</sup>. Mediante la consola de gestión del servidor puedes consultar los elementos del JNDI.

Para obtener los datos, dos opciones:

### JNDI puro y duro.

(Esto sirve también para acceder a cualquier recurso JNDI)

Cuando deployas/creas el datasource en el servidor, se le asigna un nombre de JNDI y queda accesible mediante este servicio:

```
javax.naming.Context ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:miDatasource");
```

La cuestión de los nombres es algo liosa; si recuerdo correctamente puedes acceder directamente al nombre "global" (`java:`) pero eso puede causar problemas; si tienes dos aplicaciones que usan el mismo nombre para Datasources que son distintos, no podrás tenerlas en el mismo servidor.

Así que en tu aplicación/webapp, lo que haces es indicar que Datasource usas y le asignas un nombre "local" a la aplicación; por ejemplo en el `jboss-web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/miDataSourceLocal</res-ref-name><!-- nombre local -->
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <jndi-name>java:/miDataSource</jndi-name><!-- nombre global -->
</resource-ref>
```

Esto te crea una entrada JNDI `java:comp/env/jdbc/miDataSourceLocal` que es la que usas en tu código:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/miDataSourceLocal");
```

### @Resource

En instancias gestionadas por el servidor (que tú no haces `new`, sino que crea el servidor, como p.ej. Servlets y EJBs), puedes usar `@Resource` y dejar que el servidor inyecte el Datasource:

```
@Resource(name="miDataSourceLocal")
private javax.sql.DataSource myDB
```

Esto sencillamente te automatiza el acceso al JNDI, así que la parte de gestionar los nombres para evitar colisiones también se aplica aquí.

<sup>1</sup> Si recuerdo correctamente, JBoss te obliga a esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente explicación.

Comment: Una pregunta @SJuan76, el tag `<resource-ref>` lo adiciono en el archivo `web.xml` que ya existe o debo crear uno obligatorio??

Comment: Toda la información que veo al respecto indica que `<jndi-name>` no es parte del estándar de `web.xml` y debería ir en el `jboss-web.xml`(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for). Es posible que si lo pones en el `web.xml` y deployas en JBoss no pase nada y lo procese bien, pero te podría dar problemas en otros servidores.

Answer (score 1):

después de buscar y buscar me encuentro con lo que necesitaba en este enlace http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=127

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*; 
import javax.sql.*;

/** 
 Get a connection to a database.
 Callers need to close the connection when finished.  
*/
final class GetConnection {

  /** Preferred style, using JNDI and Datasource. */
  Connection getJNDIConnection(){
    String DATASOURCE_CONTEXT = "java:comp/env/jdbc/blah";
    Connection result = null;
    try {
      Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
      //cast is necessary
      DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
      if (datasource != null) {
        result = datasource.getConnection();
      }
      else {
        log("Failed to lookup datasource.");
      }
    }
    catch (NamingException ex) {
      log("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
      log("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }
    return result;
  }
```