# java.lang.NullPointerException - Conexiones desde JNDI siempre nulas

Tags: java-ee, java-8, jboss-eap

Días atras solicite ayuda para obtener una conexión a dbase de datos a través de JNDI ( [Obtener conexión a base de datos a través del datasource del servidor de aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206465/obtener-conexi%c3%b3n-a-base-de-datos-a-trav%c3%a9s-del-datasource-del-servidor-de-aplicac/206563?noredirect=1#comment385719_206563) ), bien las conexiones funcionaron, sin embargo el JNDI lo tengo como constante dentro del código por lo cual estoy intentando configurarlo en los descriptores de la aplicación pero cada vez que solicito una conexión presenta error al crearla, realice las siguientes acciones

archivo standalone.xml (en el servidor jboss eap 7.1)

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/datasources/DATASOURCEBD" pool-name="APLICACIONWEB" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
  <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.57:1521:ORCL</connection-url>
  <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
  <driver>OracleJDBCDriver</driver>
  <security>
    <user-name>USERDB</user-name>
    <password>CLAVE</password>
  </security>
  <validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
  </validation>
</datasource>
```

Cree el archivo jboss-web.xml y coloque

```
<jboss-web>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/AppDSLocal</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/datasources/DATASOURCEBD</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

En el archivo web.xml configure

```
<web-app>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/AppDSLocal</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Clase que maneja las conexiones

```
public final class DBHelper {

  @Resource(name = "jdbc/AppDSLocal")
  private DataSource datasource;

  public Connection getConecction() {
    try {
      Connection connection =  datasource.getConnection();
      return connection;
    }
    catch(NamingException ne) {
      throw new PersistenceException("Error al obtener conexion", ne);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle) {
      throw new PersistenceException("Error ", sqle);
    }
  }
}
```

Este es el error que genera al momento de obneter la conexion

```
01:14:27,145 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) null
01:14:27,147 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.lang.NullPointerException
01:14:27,154 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
01:14:27,155 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
01:14:27,156 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
01:14:27,157 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
01:14:27,158 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
01:14:27,161 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
01:14:27,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
01:14:27,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
01:14:27,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
01:14:27,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
01:14:27,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
01:14:27,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
01:14:27,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
01:14:27,167 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
01:14:27,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
01:14:27,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
01:14:27,171 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
01:14:27,172 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
01:14:27,173 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
01:14:27,173 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
01:14:27,174 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
01:14:27,175 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
01:14:27,178 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
01:14:27,179 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
01:14:27,179 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
01:14:27,180 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
01:14:27,181 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
01:14:27,181 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
01:14:27,182 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
01:14:27,183 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
01:14:27,185 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
01:14:27,186 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
01:14:27,188 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
01:14:27,189 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
01:14:27,189 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
01:14:27,190 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
01:14:27,191 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
01:14:27,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
01:14:27,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
01:14:27,194 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
01:14:27,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
01:14:27,195 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
01:14:27,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
01:14:27,196 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
01:14:27,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
01:14:27,197 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
01:14:27,198 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
01:14:27,199 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
01:14:27,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
01:14:27,202 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
01:14:27,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
01:14:27,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
01:14:27,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
01:14:27,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
01:14:27,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
01:14:27,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
01:14:27,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
01:14:27,213 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

No se si tengo alguna configuración errada o deba importar dependencias, es un proyecto maven. muchas gracias

Comment: nos podrías compartir la traza completa del error por favor.

Comment: Prueba a hacer `@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/AppDSLocal")`. En otro orden de cosas, es mejor que enuncies la cuestión de forma que sea más fácil identificar el problema "@Resource no pone valor a un DataSource"; un enunciado que habla de `NullPointerException` no informa cuál es el verdadero problema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for

Comment: @SJuan76,       Si ya realice las diferentes configuraciones en el `@Resource`, `java:com/env/jdbc/AppDSLocal` y `AppDSLocal`, tambien actualice la publicación con el stack completo del error.